# Does setting the same data trigger an onUpdate function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Consider that you have a collection called `user` with documents such as:

```kotlin
data class User(
        val name: String = ""
)
```

And also have a **google** cloud function which is triggered `onUpdate`.

What happens if I do this for an non-existing document:

```kotlin
fs.collection("users").document("new-user").set(hashMapOf("name" to "Jane"), SetOptions.merge())
```

and later do this again (now document exists):

```kotlin
fs.collection("users").document("new-user").set(hashMapOf("name" to "Jane"), SetOptions.merge())
```

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events):

> onUpdate: Triggered when a document already exists and has any value changed.

I want to know if my function is triggered in my example (no field has been updated).
No property of the collection has been updated, but I am guessing that some metadata (e.g. update timestamp) must have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

If the `set` call does not change any value, none of the functions `onWrite` and `onUpdate` will be updated independently of the merge settings.

However, the fields that will be updated on the `set` operation depend on the `SetOptions` [from documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SetOptions).

> public static SetOptions merge ()
>
> Changes the behavior of set() calls
>   to only replace the values specified in its data argument. Fields
>   omitted from the set() call will remain untouched.